# Differences in evolution and comorbidities between NAFLD-PCOS and NAFLD in general?

Tags: pcos, fatty-liver-disease

Research showed that women, diagnosed with polycystic ovary syndrome (PCOS), have an increased risk of developing nonalcoholic fatty liver disease (NAFLD).

After an extensive literature search, there seems to be little to no research devoted to the differences in evolution of NAFLD-PCOS and NAFLD in general, and the therewith related (potentially) different comorbidities.

It would be a great help, if anyone could share some insights or provide some links to studies with regard to this topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pathophysiology of NAFLD is not fully understood, so it makes sense that there isn't much literature exploring differences in pathophysiology between people with PCOS and people without. There is an excellent explanation of the current understanding of NAFLD pathophysiology in [this review article - see "Pathogenesis"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5127277/). You'll notice a lot of "this suggests" languages as opposed to "we know this is what happens."

I found a few review articles that suggest PCOS is a risk factor for NAFLD because people with PCOS are more likely to be obese, and more likely to have metabolic syndrome - insulin resistance, high cholesterol and triglycerides, etc. I've included a list below. There may also be other hormonal influences. Several of the review articles suggest that hyperandrogenism in PCOS can contribute to fast progression of NAFLD, for example, but the evidence is inconsistent (i.e. not every study has found an association).

I'm not sure what you mean by "different comorbidities." Most common comorbidities with NAFLD are also common with PCOS, such as type 2 diabetes. If you mean complications of NAFLD, there is some evidence that PCOS is associated with faster progression of NAFLD (see review articles below), so all complications could be more common.

Review Articles:

- [Endocrine Reviews Review Article on NAFLD from Endocrine Reviews](https://academic.oup.com/edrv/article/41/1/66/5601173) - nice section on potential endocrine influences under "Epidemiology of NAFLD"
- [World Journal of Gastroenterology Review Article on NAFLD & PCOS (1)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4093689/) - mostly focuses on screening & treatment
- [World Journal of Gastroenterology Review Article on NAFLD & PCOS (2)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4202347/) - large section on possible pathogenesis mechanisms for NAFLD in PCOS
- [Clinical & Translational Endocrinology Review Article on NAFLD & PCOS](https://eje.bioscientifica.com/view/journals/eje/177/3/EJE-16-1063.xml) - focuses on hormonal influences on NAFLD
- [Reproductive Health Meta-analysis on NAFLD & PCOS](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5946415/#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20results%20of,risk%20of%20NAFLD%20than%20controls.) - suggests relationship between NAFLD & PCOS may be independent of features like obesity and insulin resistance